# Issue after Flutter Firebase upgrade? ARC Semantic Issue (Xcode): No known class method for selector 'appleCredentialWithIDToken:rawNonce:fullName:'

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase, podfile, pubspec

After Xcode build done of flutter run, I met the error as below.
I'm not sure what the reason is, I think this is because of flutter 3.10.0 upgrade. but not sure the reason.
Please help me to guide.

```
This will generate a JSON format file containing all messages that 
need to be translated.
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           10.1s
ARC Semantic Issue (Xcode): No known class method for selector 'appleCredentialWithIDToken:rawNonce:fullName:'

/Users/paulinahernandez/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-4.6.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:592:26


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```

podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.3.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  #pod 'MLKitVision', :podspec => 'MLKitVision.podspec.json'
  #pod 'MLKitCommon', :podspec => 'MLKitCommon.podspec.json'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.3.0'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations: 
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0 

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1 
  extended_image: ^6.3.1
  http: ^0.13.5
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  mvc_pattern: ^8.12.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.0.2
  mobile_scanner: ^3.2.0
  flutter_slider_drawer: ^2.1.1
  pretty_qr_code: ^2.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.2
  carousel_indicator: ^1.0.6
  time_elapsed: ^0.2.6
  url_launcher: ^6.1.6
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.2.0
  pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0
  custom_refresh_indicator: ^2.0.1
  liquid_pull_to_refresh: ^3.0.1
  audioplayers: ^3.0.1
  firebase: ^9.0.3
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6
  provider: ^6.0.4
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.10.0
  animated_check: ^1.0.5
  google_translator: ^1.0.0
  flutter_translate: ^4.0.3
  cloud_functions: ^4.0.6
  firebase_core: ^2.4.0
  firebase_app_check: ^0.1.2+1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.3.0
  flutter_app_badger: ^1.5.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
  badges: ^3.0.2
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.4
  geolocator: ^8.2.0
  geocoding: ^2.0.4
  geoflutterfire2: ^2.3.14
  socket_io_client: ^2.0.1
  internet_file: ^1.2.0
  pdfx: ^2.3.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.6

dependency_overrides:
  intl: 0.18.0
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I tried many methods including podfile change and package upgrade,
but it couldn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and tried changing the following in the Podfile:

```
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.9.0'
```

Then run `pod repo update` and `pod update`; this worked for me.